# Big delay before actual test run in VS2019

Tags: nuget, vstest

There is 20 sec delay each time I am running unit test in Visual Studio 2019. I have diagnostics test log turned on and I can see the delay is caused by many of those entries.

*Failed to determine installation location for NuGet package <*PackageName*> referenced in project <*ProjectName*>. Check to make sure that a NuGet restore operation has been performed for this project and that no errors were reported during this operation.*

I am using:

NunitTestAdapter 3.17.1 and custom nuget.config located in the same directory path as .sln file.

When I run the test in Visual Studio 2017 there is no delay

Why the test run trying to determine nuget package location? How to prevent this?